# Inject an @ variable into src of an IFRAME

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have a dynamic url that I'm building in my controller to serve as the src of the IFRAME.  I'm currently saving the url as @iframe_url.  When I go to the IFRAME on the view I'm doing

```
<IFRAME src=<%=@iframe_url%> />
```

to no avail.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you should always enclose attributes in quotes:

```
<IFRAME src="<%= @iframe_url %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're assigning the variable in the action/method you are executing to see the frame show up? Perhaps you could show some of your controller code?